# clojure jdbc error of "A RowCount was expected but not generated from query"

Tags: jdbc, clojure

I have the following code to gather table statistics on vertica database.

```
(j/execute! db ["SELECT analyze_histogram('mytable',100)"])
```

But it throws the following error. What's the correct way to run the sql?

```
SQLDataException [Vertica][JDBC](11320) A RowCount was expected but not generated from query "SELECT analyze_histogram('
mytable',100)". Query not executed.   com.vertica.exceptions.ExceptionConverter.toSQLException (:-1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `query` fn, according to [this cookbook](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/06_databases/6-03_manipulating-an-SQL-database.asciidoc).

```
(jdbc/query db ["SELECT analyze_histogram('mytable',100)"]))
```